# res.json not returning response

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

My res.json in my first block of code works, but in the else part of my if statement, it does not. The block that doesnt work, checks for a record in a database then im trying to return the response but im not receiving it.

I've checked and the response is a string, I thought it would have worked as the top part of the code successfully returns the string and it shows in dialogflow (where im trying to return it)

The response is successfully consoled right before the res.json but I do not receive it from the source of the request.

code:

```
app.post('/webhook/orderinfo', (req, res) => {

const intent = req.body.queryResult.intent.displayName;
const domain = "chatbotdemo.myshopify.com";
const order = req.body.queryResult.parameters["number-sequence"];
if (intent.includes('Order Number')) {
    url = "https://test-hchat.com/api/orders/" + domain + "/" + order;
    request(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            order_res = JSON.parse(response)
            order_res["fullfillmentText"] = "Hi, Please find your order details below:";
            res.json({
                "fulfillmentText": JSON.stringify(order_res)
            })
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });

// THIS PART DOESNT RETURN THE RESPONSE.
} else {
    const domain = 'testStore'
    db.getClientsDialog(domain, intent, (response) => {
        const fullResponse = response.response
        res.json({
            fullResponse
        })
    })
}

});
```

The database code:

```
    getClientsDialog: function (domain, intent, callback) {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://efwefewf@wefwef.mlab.com:15799/wefwef', function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var db = client.db('asdsad');
        db.collection('dialog').findOne({ domain: domain, intent: intent }, function (err, doc) {
            if (!err) {
                callback(doc)
            } else {
                throw err;
                callback(err)
            }
            client.close();
        });
        console.dir("Called findOne");
    });
}
```

Could it be because this second use of the res.json in the else statement, is trying to call the db first and therefore the link is lost to send the data back?

Comment: Please check if it is going in else part or not. And check value of fullResponse.

Comment: Hi Sagar, it does go in because it consoles and it consoles fullResponse as expected, the string value

Comment: have you tried without object destructing?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean... can my res.json be this format: "wdedewfe": "fefefef".. ? or does it need the proper json structure? or can i use res.send?

Comment: What happens if you send static json? Does that work?

Comment: Those missing semicolons possibly don't help.

Comment: Hi @FredGandt, would they actually do anything?

Comment: Always rule out the simplest and most obvious possible errors first when debugging. Correcting syntax, even the sugar, can often either fix the problems or at least highlight where they might be. In the worst case, ensuring your code is properly formatted does absolutely no harm, even if it does no good. Consider that the very part of the code that's malfunctioning has multiple missing semicolons; it won't hurt to address that first.